# Resultado None y []

Tags: python, eclipse, csv

Estoy  intentando hacer un código para ejecutar unas funciones para un trabajo de clase con Python pero me sale un error que no consigo solucionar: `TypeError: filtrador_de_genero() missing 1 required positional argument: 'genre'`

```py
def lee_datos(fichero):
    
    with open(fichero,'r', encoding ='utf-8') as f:
        
        lector = csv.reader(f)
        next(lector)
        registrados = [Pelicudato(int(ranking),movie_name,genre,int(year),int(timeMin),float(imdb),float(metascore),int(vote),float(us_grossMillions))
                    for ranking, movie_name, genre, year, timeMin, imdb, metascore, vote, us_grossMillions in  lector]     
                   
        
        
            
        
    return registrados 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#SEGUNDA FUNCIÓN
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
f = lee_datos('../data/movies_IMDB.csv')
def filtrador_de_genero(registrados,genero):   
    res = [r for r in registrados if r.genre==genero]
```

Desde aqui es donde intento llamar a la funcion

```
filtrazo = filtrador_de_genero(datazo, 'Action')
print(filtrazo)
```

Pero solo me devuelve una lista vacía `[]` y `None`.

Comment: a simple vista, lo único que veo mal es el `append`, ya que no estas agregando nada, solo haces referencia al método pero no lo ejecutas. Luego no tengo idea del error que mencionas ya que todo esta correcto. Tal vez esas funciones pertenecen a una clase??

Comment: ¿Llamas a `filtrador_de_genero()` desde algún otro lugar? (¿o es llamada desde algún test que tu código no pasa?) ¿Es alguna de las funciones que muestras un método de una clase? Revisa el código completo y edita la pregunta para ampliar información si es necesario.

Comment: @abulafia si lo llamo desde otro lugar que es donde me da el fallo

Comment: Pues tendrías que haber puesto el código que te está dando el fallo, si solo pones código correcto ¿cómo vamos a encontrar dónde está el error? Verifica que en todos los lugares en que llamas a `filtrador_de_genero()` le estás pasando dos parámetros, pues el error te dice que falta el segundo.

Comment: Fácil. Solo le estas pasando la ruta del archivo a tu función pero necesita que le pases el segundo parámetro que seria el genero a filtrar. Luego tendrás otro error dado que la función espera que el primer parámetro sea el archivo abierto y tu solo le pasas un simple string

Comment: @Christian muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Te devuelve eso por que no hay ningún `return` en ninguna de tus funciones

Comment: @Stfuirlv Has editado la pregunta para cambiarle el título y lo que preguntas al final. En cambio al inicio sigues mencionando que tienes el error "missing 1 required positional argument: 'genre'", lo que ya no es cierto porque en la edición de la pregunta has corregido ese error. Además, debido a esos cambios, ya no se entienden todos los comentarios previos que habíamos hecho en la pregunta. Te pediría por favor que dejes la pregunta como estaba antes (para que tenga algún sentido para quien la lea), y si acaso que añadas una sección "Ampliación", o hagas otra pregunta para la nueva consulta

Comment: has cambiado mucho la pregunta, por lo que los comentarios pierden sentido y esto se considera una pregunta nueva ya que este error no tiene nada que ver con el anterior. Te pediría que vuelvas a editar la pregunta para dejarla como antes y si deseas agregar tu propia respuesta. De lo contrario deberé revertir las ediciones para que la pregunta y comentarios tengan coherencia.

Answer (score 0):

Si te devuelve None es porque no has declarado un return, por tanto, `filtrazo` = None.

```
def filtrador_de_genero(registrados,genero):   
    res = [r for r in registrados if r.genre==genero]
    return res
```

Por otra parte, el error `missing 1 required positional argument`, si tu código es exactamente como lo has escrito aquí, no debería aparecer, ya que estás llamando a la función con dos argumentos, exactamente como está declarada.